# CodeNameOne Dial Issue

Tags: codenameone

I've developed a mobile app which need to dial a number automatically within the APP.
I use Display.getInstance().dial(xxxxxxx) but when this function is called just the dialer application comes up and appears without dialing and user needs to push the dial button within the dial application on Android.

I understand that dial() function just runs native dialer but I'm looking for a solution that dials automatically as well, because currently my App doesn't dial automatically  as I tested it in different phones but my competitor APP which has been developed using native Android SDK works perfect and dials automatically.

Any idea?

Best Regards
Mani

Comment: Even in native Android there's no simple way to make the call automatically, unless you build your own dialer.  Otherwise you have to look up the appropriate package to make sure it's installed on the device, and if it's not (for instance, Samsung phones have a different dialer app they use, not the one provided by Google), you're back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't builtin to Codename One since its pretty specific to Android, you can probably use [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to achieve that result.